# Defining the height and length of an image

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Dear stackoverflow community,

I guess I have a relatively easy problem but nonetheless, I have no idea how to solve it.

So I have this figure which is a map of a town I live in. Since Matlab can't possibly know that it is a map, the heigth and length are measured in pixels (I suppose). However, I would love to find or to define realisitic values in that way that it is measured in meters/kilometers, since I'm coding a car sharing simulator and its not that elegant that they lose a certain amount of charge per pixel. Therefore, I'd love to define beforehand that we're dealing with meters instead of pixels without changing the actual size of the figure. So let's imagine that the picture has a resolution of 1024x768 and I want Matlab to interpret this "solution" as 5 km width and 3 km height.

Right now, I simply use imread:

```
hf = figure();
[B, map] = imread('Hannoverosm.png');
C = imresize(B, 0.975);
imshow(C, map)
```

Comment: What do you want to do with those values? Compute distances (in km) between pixels? It doesn't make much sense to attach a distance interpretation to an image unless you define what you will do with that

Comment: The problem isn't that you are using pixels instead of km but that you have "only" 1024x768 data points. If you transform your whole program in km by defining X: 1pixel = 5(km)/1024 and same for Y: 1pixel =3(km)/768  you will have to differentiate between x and y directions and you may get adressing problems by adressing a km(m) place which doesn't belong to a pixel.

Comment: You're right, I need these values for computing distances and it's respective impacts on functions that work with these values. As I said, right now cars lose charge per pixel and not per meter. Actually, I couldnt care less but the person that is grading the whole work won't be able to follow my decisions on the consumption of fuel/charge. Moreover, they wan't to use my code after I graduated and therefore, it has to be easily accessable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just create functions to covert from your pixel space to your km space?

```
function km = pixels2km(pixels)
    km = pixels*(5/1024);
end

function pixels = km2pixels(km)
    pixels = km*(1024/5);
end
```

Actually these calculations are so simple you probably don't even need the functions. Also since pixel space is discrete you need to decide on the best method for rounding (probably `floor` or `ceil` depending on which corner you're making the 'origin'

Comment: Well thanks for the input. Now I realize how stupid my question was, since I already calculate the distance between points and I solely have to multiply or divide it by a realistic factor.